# Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) in the top level call of Azure WebJobsSDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobssdk

I am using Windows Azure with the WebJobsSDK and I was wondering if, when calling aync methods, I should add ConfigureAwait(false) to the awaited calls.  In other words, does the SDK require the async methods to return to the original context to continue to function properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does the SDK require the async methods to return to the original context to continue to function properly?

I don't know the answer to this question; it *may* depend on the host. That is, the SDK itself won't require a particular context, but the host might.

However, I'd say it doesn't matter. Considering this question:

> Should I use ConfigureAwait(false) in the top level call of Azure WebJobsSDK

If the context is required, then the host will provide a context, and you shouldn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

If there is no context, then the host will not provide a context, and it won't matter whether you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or not.

If there is a context provided but it's not required, then using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will reduce your overhead by a tiny, tiny amount - not something to lose sleep over.

So, I'd say that capturing the context (i.e., not using `ConfigureAwait(false)`) is the safest solution across any host.